# Content Porter for non-admin user import errors

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

**Updated Question**

The import is successful when a user without admin access, assigned to default user group (e.g. chief editor or editor or author).

The import fails when a user without admin access, assigned to a non-default user group (e.g. senior developer).

Only difference is that default user groups have rights assigned to them on parent publication 000 Empty Parent.
Non-default user groups do not have rights assigned to them on parent publication.

The User assigned Group has

- Read/Write permissions on Schemas Folder.
- Read/Write/Delete/Localize permissions on all other Folders.
- All rights except for customer, permission, workflow mgmt, publish to content distributor, translation management/configuration.
- Does not have access to parent publication.

**Content porter Import exception**
[image]

Event log does not provide detailed information on the cause of the error. 
[image]
   [image]

What missing permissions might cause this error? Could there be a content porter configuration change to allow non-admins for content porting?

Comment: Can you check the Windows event log for the Content Manager and get the details from the error there? When you import through Content Porter, you are using the Import/Export API, and that logs detailed errors on each failing action, explaining what exactly went wrong. For example it could be due to related items on which the user doesn't have permissions etc. etc. Please **edit** your question and update it with the details from the CM event log.

Comment: Is the user able to login and manually perform the same action? (access the specific publication, open in edit mode and amend (or create) the item in question?

Also - with regards the logging - have you activated verbose logging?

Comment: I would confirm the previous two points first, but I'd also add other permissions (one at a time) - if it works, try removing the other to confirm "that's" the one... then perhaps update this so we can drill down and investigate more?

Comment: Updated question with event log details. The user is able to login and manually create a new component or update the existing component in the target environment for the item in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace reveals that the permissions denied exception occurs when loading a Repository/Publication.

So, apparently the user does not have permission to read some of the three Publications which are listed (that is: the user does not have any Rights on some of those Publications).  I expect that the user won’t see all of these Publications in the CME either.

Comment: The user has access to all publications shown in the screenshot, except for the parent publication. Giving 'user group' access to the parent publication resolved the content porter import/export issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the content porting has failed mainly because of either of this reason:

1. Selecting more items than required for porting. To avoid this, when performing porting, if you know the specific items that are to be content ported then use the option given below in the snapshot "selected children only" to select that particular item only and exclude all other items.

[image: Image from http://monicamanzano.blogspot.com/2012/12/moving-items-around-within-single.html]

2. Other issue that I have seen is schema mismatch between source and target environment.

Comment: During import we do select 'Selected children only' checkbox.
The component schema used by the component, had field descriptions different in the source and target environments. After syncing up the description fields, import still fails.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that the permissions failure is for the NETWORK SERVICE account. Check your server configuration to ensure that authentication is correctly set up, and that impersonation is correctly configured.

Answer (score -2):

**You do not have permission to perform this action. Please check your user permissions. you need write access to perform this action.**

If you configure Content Porter to prompt you for failing items, you can fix a number of problems during import. If an item fails, you can fix the problem and click Retry. Then the Content Porter again tries to import the item, and if successful, continues the import.

Fixing failing items during the import process itself is logical if you expect the process to be short and failures to be few. It requires you to sit through the process from start to finish.

**No permission to write to Content Manager**

Fix this problem by changing the privileges of the Content Manager user.

**Item to update is in workflow**

Finish activity on the item.

**Item to update is checked out**

**Check in the item.**

**Component invalid according to Schema**

Update the Schema. Note that this affects all other Component based on this Schema.

**Filtered dependency not found on destination Content Manager**

Create the missing dependency manually in Content Manager Explorer.

Comment: As mentioned, the user has r/w permissions setup on the folder, components, publication and schema used by component. Could there be a configuration change required to allow non-admins?

Comment: Not required any configuration change for non-admin. Please check content porting user have the write permission for folder,component publication and schema.  Please login CMS and create folder,component manual and check the permissions.

Comment: @SudhakarRao If you quote the documentation *directly* - you should acknowledge this. https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1/GUID-20434784-1B54-4C6F-B9D3-1FFC8E7EC52A